# How to set iterations under different conditions for While loop in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am quite new to codig and trying to execute the following peice of code with if conditions in while loop. The increments for w and t under if conditions do not work. Does anybody have a solution?

```
d=[2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3]
c=np.empty(15)
w=0
t=0
while w<6 and t<15:
    x = sum(d[:w])/(t+1) 
    if x==1:
        c[t]=1
        w+=1
        t+=1
    if x!=1:
        c[t]=0
        t+=1
```

Comment: Is x EXACTLY the value you want? It probably doesn't equals to 1, as you're doing a division. Just note that 1.1 is different from 1, so the if wouldn't match. (You can provide the value for `d` so we can try reproducing it)

Comment: What are `d` and `c`?  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72046822/edit) the question to include a [mcve].

Comment: The problem is not regarding the value of x since the example takes care of integrality. The issue is the increment for w and t appear not to work when x==1, and the code calculates c as a vector of zeros. c needs to be [0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand well what you want to do but, in line 6 (`x = sum(d[:w])/(t+1)`) remember that you initialized 'w' as 0, so you are not taking any sample from 'd', in consequence, 'x' will always be 0. Hope that will solve your problem.